# Invariant Violation: Minified React error #62

Tags: reactjs

I wrote the following method inside a react component and everything works fine

```
render() { return (
   <div>
      <div>
         <AppHeader x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} />
         <Button id = {0} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {1} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {2} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {3} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
      <div>
         <ScoreBoard correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
      </div>
   </div>
)}
```

But the 2 divs appear one on top of another. I changed my code to

```
render() { return (
   <div>
      <div style='float:left'>
         <AppHeader x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} />
         <Button id = {0} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {1} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {2} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         <Button id = {3} x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} answerKey = {this.state.answerKey} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
      <div style='float:right'>
         <ScoreBoard correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
      </div>
   </div>
)}
```

But as soon as I put the style left and right. I get an error

```
Invariant Violation: Minified React error #62; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=62&args[]=%20This%20DOM%20node%20was%20rendered%20by%20%60Quiz%60. for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

I don't understand this error at all.. why is the style='float:left' such a big deal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Style expects a Javascript object of styles. What you have provided is a string.

```
<div style={{float: 'right'}}>
   <ScoreBoard correct={this.state.correct} incorrect={this.state.incorrect} />
</div>
```

From the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: Thanks, I almost forgot there are two syntaxes {} and {{}} ones.

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy there is actually only one syntax which is `prop={expression}` if we don't count regular `prop="value"`. It just so happens that an object also uses curly braces and thus sometimes you end up with double pairs `prop={{key: 'value'}}`. Rest assured that "double curly brace" is not a syntax, just a visual side effect of using an expression value for a property with a plain object :)

Comment: @SidOfc very true, non-object example is also in above answer itself :-), correct={this.state.correct} -- however won't it be good if we have simpler prop={key: 'value'} when its an object? :-), why is it not like this simpler way now, what's a usecase where this simpler way will fail if allowed by react?

Comment: Well, whatever you put inside `{` and `}` is evaluated as a JavaScript expression, as long as it's valid it'll work. The interpreter on the other hand first has to _know_ via the outer curly braces, that you intend to execute a JS expression inside. Only after identifying that you want to execute an expression can it "do something" with whatever is _inside_ the outer curly braces. Now imagine just running a JS with the ONLY content being `key1: 'value', key2: 123` and literally nothing else, does it make sense in this context?

Comment: And of course, parsers can be made smart to handle such cases, but this makes them more difficult to extend in the long run and may end up limiting a language at some point even. (apologies for spam, complex topic, didn't quite fit one paragraph). Well, quite some text but hope it helps, once again apologies for spam SO mods :D